# Dynamic URL Rewrite for Custom

Tags: plugins, functions, url-rewriting, regex

I have a custom post type called `Hotels` which I woud like to link to using the below url structure:
`/{country}/{state}/{hotel-name}`

I am fetching and inserting posts dynamically, so I do not know the number of countries/states.

The Hotel Name is the slug version of the post title.

I have been banging my head all day trying to get it to work.
The below code works to make the links look correct, but then 404s on all posts:

```
function change_link($permalink, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type == 'hotels') {
        $country = get_field('location_country', $post->ID);
        $state = get_field('location_state', $post->ID);

        $permalink = get_home_url() . "/hotels/"
            . (!empty($country) ? slugify($country) . '/' : '')
            . (!empty($state) ? slugify($state) . '/' : '')
            . $post->post_name;
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', "change_link", 10, 2);
```

I then tried adding a rewrite rule, but I don't fully understand what it is doing and why it is not working:

```
function generate_rule($wp_rewrite)
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '/hotels/([^/].+?)/([^/].+?)/([^;?]+)',
        'index.php?post_type=hotels&name=$matches[3]&country=$matches[1]&state=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'generate_rule');
```

Woud be much appreciated if someone can point me in the right direction...

Comment: did you re-save your permalinks/flush them after changing the rewrite rule? And have you used one of the rewrite rules debugger plugins to test that your URL matches your rule and not a different rule? Order can be significant. Also, did you test the ugly permalink you're rewriting to? And do you really need to include the country and state in your rewrite rule match? Would it be enough for them to just be decorative? Note that `post_type_link` might not change the permalink of the post, just the URL string when it's displayed.

Comment: Have you considered setting up a hierarchical `Location` taxonomy instead of using custom fields? I think core functionality with `"rewrite" => [ "hierarchical" => true, "with_front" => false ]` would largely handle this situation - plus you'd get the benefit of core aggregation/archives for locations

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes I did re-save the permalinks

Comment: @bosco I did consider that, but the categories/taxonomy will be used for another purpose (i.e. tagging each hotel with categories like "beachfront" etc) meaning I cannot have the state/country in there